# Are there any obvious problems with this chain of logic/code?

Tags: c#, multithreading, queue

One of the books I'm reading is "The Art of Multiprocessor Programming, by Maurice Herlihy and Nir Shavit". In it, there is a "wait-free" queue which (after a bit of language adaption) functions test- and logic-perfectly in a threaded environment - At the least, there are no collisions even on 10,000,000 items distributed across 5 threads and the logic checks out.

(I edited the queue to return false if an item could not be gotten, instead of throwing an exception. The code is given below).

However, it has one caveat; the queue cannot grow. A cursory logic checks states that it cannot grow without locking the queue - Which would somewhat negate the point of having a lock-free queue.

The purpose, then, is to create a lock-free (or at least, starvation-free locking) queue which can grow.

So: If we, essentially, give each thread their own shared queue, in a way that is not an oxymoron (and accepting the high probability that this has been solved and better for the purpose of learning-by-doing):

```
        WaitFreeQueue<Queue<int>> queues = new WaitFreeQueue<Queue<int>>(threadCount);

        // Dequeue a queue, enqueue an item, enqueue the queue.

        // Dequeue a queue, dequeue an item, enqueue the queue.
```

And the wait-free queue (Previous code included in comments in case I make any breaking changes):

```
/// <summary>
/// A wait-free queue for use in threaded environments.
/// Significantly adapted from "The Art of Multiprocessor Programming by Maurice Herlihy and Nir Shavit".
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The type of item in the queue.</typeparam>
public class WaitFreeQueue<T>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The index to dequeue from.
    /// </summary>
    protected int head;
    /// <summary>
    /// The index to queue to.
    /// </summary>
    protected int tail;
    /// <summary>
    /// The array to queue in.
    /// </summary>
    protected T[] items;


    /// <summary>
    /// The number of items queued.
    /// </summary>
    public int Count
    {
        get { return tail - head; }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new wait-free queue.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="capacity">The capacity of the queue.</param>
    public WaitFreeQueue(int capacity)
    {
        items = new T[capacity];
        head = 0; tail = 0;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Attempts to enqueue an item.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value">The item to enqueue.</param>
    /// <returns>Returns false if there was no room in the queue.</returns>
    public bool Enqueue(T value)
    {
        if (tail - head == items.Length)
            // throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
            return false;
        items[tail % items.Length] = value;
        System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(ref tail);
        return true;
        // tail++;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Attempts to dequeue an item.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="r">The variable to dequeue to.</param>
    /// <returns>Returns true if there was an available item to dequeue.</returns>
    public bool Dequeue(out T r)
    {
        if (tail - head == 0)
        // throw new InvalidOperationException("No more items.");
        { r = default(T); return false; }
        r = items[head % items.Length];
        System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(ref head);
        // head++;
        // return r;
        return true;
    }
}
```

So: Would this work? If not, why? If so, are there still any foreseeable problems?

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you just use `ConcurrentQueue<T>`? Or is this a learning exercise?

Comment: How would you handle the case if two threads are simultaneously calling `Enqueue`, and the control switches from the first thread to the second one after the first one executes `items[tail % items.Length] = value;`?

Comment: My understanding is, it doesn't read and write to the same location at the exact same time, so no collisions. Truthfully, I probably need to re-read the logic section again, but both tests and my understanding says it works. Granted, I'm a little fuzzy on how, but I'm learning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Trying to write lock-free multi-threaded code is hard, and you should either leave it to people who know it better than you or me (and use e.g. `ConcurrentQueue<T>`), or not write it at all (and use locks), if possible.

That being said, there are several problems with your code:

1. It's not a queue. If `threadCount` is 2, and you enqueue items 1, 2 and 3, one after another, and then you dequeue, you get item 2!
2. You can't first use the value of a field and then call `Interlocked.Increment()` on it like you do. Imagine something like this:

   1. On thread 1: `items[tail % items.Length] = value;`
   2. On thread 2: `items[tail % items.Length] = value;`
   3. On thread 2: `Interlocked.Increment(ref head);`
   4. On thread 1: `Interlocked.Increment(ref head);`

   Now, both threads enqueued to the same position and the position after that didn't change. This is wrong.

Comment: Thanks. That thought was bugging me and is one of the reasons I posted the code. I hope I didn't buy a poor textbook. :( What would be a good way to test that?

Comment: @Narf, I'm afraid you can't really test race conditions. If you wrote a test that would fail because of it, it might succeed next time because of slightly different timing, even if you didn't fix it yet.

Comment: Thanks. At least I know the textbook is useless, now.

Comment: @Narf, I'm not so sure. The book states about this queue: “This queue is correct only if it is shared by a single enqueuer and a single dequeuer”.

Comment: @Svick: I must have missed that. What page?

Comment: @Narf, 47, the one directly before the code, see e.g. [Google Books](http://books.google.com/books?id=pFSwuqtJgxYC&pg=PA47).

Answer (score 2):

The code you posted is is not thread safe for neither enqueue nor dequeue.

**Enqueue**

- You have an empty queue
- `head = tail = 0`
- You have 2 threads trying to enqueue.
- First thread executes `Enqueue` and gets interrupted after `items[tail % items.Length] = value;` but before executing the interlocked increment. It has now written a value into `item[0]` but not incremented `tail`
- Second thread enters `Enqueue` and executes the method. Now `tail` is still 0 and therefore the value written by the previous thread is replaced as the second thread will write a value into `item[0]` as well.
- Both threads finish the excution.
- The item count will be correct but you will have lost data.

**Dequeue**

- Assume you have two items in the queue at `item[0]` and `items[1]`
- `head = 0` and `tail = 2`
- You have two threads trying to dequeue.
- The fist thread gets into `Dequeue` and gets interrupted after `r = items[head % items.Length];` but before executing the interlocked increments.
- Now the second thread enters `Dequeue` and will return the same item as `head` is still 0
- Afterwards your queue will be empty but you will have read one item twice and one item not at all.